# How to find the determinant of the following?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})\in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ be defined by

$$a_{ij} = \begin{cases} i & \text{if }i+j=n+1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then what is the value of $\det(A)$?

Comment: i'm thinking it's $(-1)^{n+1}n!$

Comment: just looking at a few simple cases, if $n=2$, $\det(A)=-2$, if $n=3, \det(A)=6$, and if $n=4, \det(A)=-24$.  Perhaps try an induction argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is an antidiagonal matrix, the determinant is just the product of the antidiagonal elements (up to sign)

Comment: is it $(-1)^{n+1}n!$?...........

Comment: @user123804 I don't think that's right. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the determinant using Laplace's expansion.

$$(1\cdot(-1)^{n-1})\cdot(2\cdot(-1)^{n-2})\cdot ... \cdot((n-1)\cdot(-1)^1)\cdot(n)=n! \cdot (-1)^{(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1}=n!(-1)^{(n-1)n/2}$$

Note that this evaluates to $n!$, if $n\equiv 0$ or $n\equiv 1$ and to $-n!$, if $n\equiv 2$ or $n\equiv 3$. (mod 4)